# resize header not working on DataTable js

Tags: css, datatables

I've got a datatable that is responsive, except for the header. The table is initialized according to the code below:

```
  $('.datatable-objects').DataTable({
    autoWidth: false,
    responsive: true,
    scrollX: true,
    dom: '<"datatable-header"fl><"datatable-scroll-wrap"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
    language: {
      search: '<span>Filter:</span> _INPUT_',
      lengthMenu: '<span>Show:</span> _MENU_',
      paginate: { 'first': 'First', 'last': 'Last', 'next': '&rarr;', 'previous': '&larr;' }
    }

  });

  // Add placeholder to the datatable filter option
  $('.dataTables_filter input[type=search]').attr('placeholder','Type to filter...');

  // Enable Select2 select for the length option
  $('.dataTables_length select').select2({
      minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
      width: 'auto'
  });

  $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').css({"width":"100%"});
  $('.datatable-objects').css({"width":"100%"});
  $('.datatable-objects').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').css({"width":"100%"});
    $('.datatable-objects').css({"width":"100%"});
  });
});
```

I need the css hacks at the end in order to make it resize appropriately on window resize. Otherwise, there is a hard size put in the width property and resizing is not working correctly.
I'm not clear on why I need to add this, while in other examples I see there is no need. Anybody a suggestion?

Comment: I would suspect `autoWidth: false` to be responsible for the inappropriate resizing ...

Comment: @davidkonrad Unfortunately that doesn't make a difference for this issue.

Comment: hey @Rudi, can you make a fiddle that reproduces the behaviour? Here is a starting point -> http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/944/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the "tbl-principal" table, then you just need to add as follows:

```
$('#tbl-principal').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
```

Remarks: if you need to resie on window resize, the code of above needs to be putted on $(window) resize function.

In my case, I´m doing a show/hide div, so... i just put the code on my function...

And that's it... It's working!